# Link Id from data in database, to custom ArrayAdapter, to listView

Tags: android, database, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a custom listview.

The data is not coming from a cursor but from an `ArrayAdapter` of my own class, which contains data coming from a cursor.

I've managed to create the custom list view, but when implement the `onListItemClick` method, then I get an id for that row, that is not the same id for that data in the database.

How do I link the _id of the items in my database into my list, using my custom `ArrayAdapter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your custom `ArrayAdapter` implement `getItemId(int position)` using the data from the cursor's _id column.  Once you've done that, it should be provided to you as the `id` argument to `onListItemClick`.

Comment: I have been searching for the solution. But finally found here.